# how to execute a postgreSql query using a .bat file

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

I instal postgreSql in my windows server 12.

And I like to run a select query using a .BAT file windows server and show to me the result of the query in cmd line or .txt file.

```
select service,count(*) from datatraces where statut = 'Error' group by service
```

Comment: Your question is not about a specific programming issue, and is therefore off topic on StackOverflow. Your question is about how to use a specific piece of software, you can find out how to do that from [the Developer's own site](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html).

Comment: Just run `psql` from within your batch file